# Refactoring a ReactJS class to a Hook issue

Tags: reactjs, contenteditable, react-hooks

I have the following class that works fine (I know that DOMSubtreeModified is depreacted, I will update this too). It's a very basic WYIWYG I'm trying to refactor to a hook:

```
export class TextEditorClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state ={
      // this props contains the html content of the contentEditable
      content: this.props.content,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // here I add a listener to the contentEditable div that calls updateContent 
    document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", () => this.updateContent(), false);
    document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = this.props.content;
    rangy.init();
  }

  setApplier(applier) {
    rangy.createClassApplier(applier, { elementTagName: "span" }).toggleSelection();
  }

  updateContent() {
    this.props.setContent('content', document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML);
    this.setState({
      content: document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='editor-content dashed'>
        <input id="myInput" type="file" ref={(ref) => this.upload = ref} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
        <div className='editor-toolbar'>
          <ButtonToolbar>
            <ButtonGroup size='xs'>
              <IconButton
                className='rsuite-btn'
                onClick={()=>this.setApplier('applierBold')}
                icon={ <Icon icon="bold"/> }
              />
              <IconButton
                className='rsuite-btn'
                onClick={()=>this.setApplier('applierItalic')}
                icon={ <Icon icon="italic"/> }
              />
              <IconButton
                className='rsuite-btn'
                onClick={()=>this.setApplier('applierHeader')}
                icon={ <Icon icon="header"/> }
              />
            </ButtonGroup>
          </ButtonToolbar>
        </div>
        <div
          suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
          id='editor'
          contentEditable  
        >
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

This is what I wrote so far:

```
export function TextEditorHook() {

  const value = React.useContext(ManagerContext);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = value.state.content;
    document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", () => updateContent(), false);
    rangy.init();
  });

  function setApplier(applier) {
    rangy.createClassApplier(applier, { elementTagName: "span" }).toggleSelection();
  }

  function updateContent() {

    value.dispatch({type: 'content', value: document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML});

  }

  return (
    <div className='editor-content dashed'>

      <div className='editor-toolbar'>
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <ButtonGroup size='xs'>
            <IconButton
              className='rsuite-btn'
              onClick={()=>setApplier('applierBold')}
              icon={ <Icon icon="bold"/> }
            />
            <IconButton
              className='rsuite-btn'
              onClick={()=>setApplier('applierItalic')}
              icon={ <Icon icon="italic"/> }
            />
            <IconButton
              className='rsuite-btn'
              onClick={()=>setApplier('applierHeader')}
              icon={ <Icon icon="header"/> }
            />
          </ButtonGroup>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </div>
      <div
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
        id='editor'
        contentEditable
      >
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But it doesn't work:

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be
>   uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to
>   uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

Second warning:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
>   component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
>   doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
>   every render.

The reason behind this I suppose is the fact that the typing triggers a loop of rerenders. Why it doesn't happen in the class?

EDIT: I believe the key to fix the issue is in `useEffect()`; I suppose it behaves differently from `componentDidMount`, in fact in the hook version I had to swap these two lines to prevent another error from occurring from this:

```
document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", () => this.updateContent(), false);
document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = this.props.content;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = this.props.content;
document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", () => this.updateContent(), false);
```

EDIT 2:

Adding `[]` as a parameter for useEffect() I got rid of the first error:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = value.state.content;
    document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", () => updateContent(), false);
    rangy.init();
  }, []);
```

More info about it here: https://dev.to/trentyang/replace-lifecycle-with-hooks-in-react-3d4n

Comment: Why are you refactoring this as a functional component with hooks? Is it an exercise for yourself so that you can learn hooks better? From the React blog: "There is no rush to migrate to Hooks. We recommend avoiding any 'big rewrites', especially for existing, complex class components. It takes a bit of a mindshift to start 'thinking in Hooks'. In our experience, it’s best to practice using Hooks in new and non-critical components first, and ensure that everybody on your team feels comfortable with them." https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#gradual-adoption-strategy

Comment: I read the code, from where is the rangy?

Comment: I want to learn how to use Hooks properly, so yes, this would be an exercise to improve. This is a project I'm working on, nothing in production.

Comment: I excluded the imports at the top. Rangy is installed with npm and imported with import rangy from 'rangy'; https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Selection

Comment: One golden question: How often do you want your `useEffect` to be executed?  when `value` changes? once?

Comment: I suppose that once is enough. I figured out that if I add [] as a parameter on useEffect I get rid of the first error.

Comment: I put my answer based on the info that I read on your question. is the `#editor` element kind of a user input?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue does not happen in React class component because `componentDidMount` is run once and you put the code of `componentDidMount` in `useEffect` without any conditions - which means it will run on each render.

Problems with your `useEffect`:

1) You are adding an event listender but you are not doing a [clean-up](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup) afterwards.

2)You are mutating the DOM directly which is an anti pattern

3)You are applying any depedencies on your `useEffect`, which execut the `useEffect` on each render and will cause a memory leak.

Here is how your code should look like: (will be writing code shortly)

```
...
const [editorValue, setEditorValue] = React.useState('')

// If you want your hook to run once
React.useEffect( () => {

    setEditorValue(value.state.content)
    document.getElementById("editor").addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", () => updateContent(), false);

    // The returning funnction will be executed on unmounting
    () => document.getElementById("editor").removeEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", () => updateContent(), false);

    // note the `[]`] as second argument. That means to run only once.
}, [])
```

And the content of your `#editor` is then the controllable state `editorValue`.

```
   <div
    suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
    id='editor'
    contentEditable
  >
     {editorValue}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Matthew's answer pointed me to the right direction, and after a bit of tweaking I came up with this code that works fine:

```
import React from 'react'

import { Icon, IconButton, ButtonGroup, ButtonToolbar  } from 'rsuite'

import rangy from 'rangy';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier';

import dompurify from 'dompurify';

import './TextEditor.css';

import { ManagerContext } from './LessonManager.js';

export function TextEditorHook() {

  const value = React.useContext(ManagerContext);

  // here I initialize the editor content with the content I receive from the provider
  const [editorValue, setEditorValue] = React.useState(value.state.content);

  React.useEffect( () => {

    rangy.init();

    const editor = document.getElementById('editor');

    // here I replaced the deprecated DOMSubtreeModified with MutationObserver
    // basically when you change the dom of the contentEditable I call dispatch
    // and update the content

    let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
      value.dispatch({type: 'content', value: editor.innerHTML});
    });

    mutationObserver.observe(editor, {
      attributes: true,
      characterData: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
      attributeOldValue: true,
      characterDataOldValue: true
    }); 

    // the cleanup can be done with .disconnect();
    return () => mutationObserver.disconnect();

  });

  function setApplier(applier) {
    rangy.createClassApplier(applier, { elementTagName: "span" }).toggleSelection();
  }

  // the createMarkup() function is used to generate the markup that I will put inside
  // my contentEditable, I installed an additional npm package (dompurify) to clean up
  // the markup to prevent XSS attacks
  // https://dev.to/jam3/how-to-prevent-xss-attacks-when-using-dangerouslysetinnerhtml-in-react-1464)

  function createMarkup() { 
    const sanitizer = dompurify.sanitize;
    return {__html: sanitizer(editorValue)}
  };

  return (
    <div className='editor-content dashed'>

      <div className='editor-toolbar'>
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <ButtonGroup size='xs'>
            <IconButton
              className='rsuite-btn'
              onClick={()=>setApplier('applierBold')}
              icon={ <Icon icon="bold"/> }
            />
            <IconButton
              className='rsuite-btn'
              onClick={()=>setApplier('applierItalic')}
              icon={ <Icon icon="italic"/> }
            />
            <IconButton
              className='rsuite-btn'
              onClick={()=>setApplier('applierHeader')}
              icon={ <Icon icon="header"/> }
            />
          </ButtonGroup>
        </ButtonToolbar>
      </div>
      <div
        suppressContentEditableWarning={true}
        id='editor'
        contentEditable
        // here I insert the html with the purified html
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()}
      >
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

To give a complete answer I will add also the parent components. This is the LessonContents component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { Input } from 'rsuite';

// TextEditorHook is the WYSIWYG component

import { TextEditorHook } from './TextEditor.js';

// this context contain the value of the lesson manager
// we will use the context for the lesson's title, desc, content and location

import { ManagerContext } from './LessonManager.js';

// truncate is a function to shorten text in order to make it fit
// maxLenght is the default max text length

import { truncate, maxLength } from '../Common.js';

export default function Menu() {

    const value = React.useContext(ManagerContext);

    useEffect(() => {

        // if not editing inject the html in the display div on load

        if (!value.editing) document.querySelector('.lesson-content').innerHTML = value.state.content;

        console.log(value);

    });

    const editorContent = () => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    <Input
                        className='rsuite-input dashed'
                        placeholder='Lesson title'
                        value={value.state.title}
                        onChange={(v) => value.dispatch({type: 'title', value: v})}
                    />


                     <Input
                        className='rsuite-input dashed'
                        componentClass="textarea"
                        rows={1}
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                        placeholder='Lesson description'
                        value={value.state.desc}
                        onChange={(v) => value.dispatch({type: 'desc', value: v})}
                    />

                    <TextEditorHook/>

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    const viewerContent = () => {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className='content'>
                    <span>{truncate(value.state.title, maxLength, false)}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='content'>
                    <span>{value.state.desc}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='content'>
                    <span>{truncate(value.state.location, maxLength, false)}</span>
                </div>
                <div className='content justify-left lesson-content'>

                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    return (

        <React.Fragment>

            {value.editing ? editorContent() : viewerContent()}

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

And finally the LessonManager component:

```
import React from 'react';

import LessonMenu from './LessonMenu.js';

// this context will be used from child components to access the lesson status

import LessonContents from './LessonContents.js';

export const ManagerContext = React.createContext(null);

const initialState = {
  title: 'Lesson title',
  desc: 'Lesson description',
  content: 'Lesson content',
  location: 'home / english'
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  console.log(action.type, action.value, state)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'title':
      return {...state, title: action.value};
    case 'desc':
      return {...state, desc: action.value};
    case 'content':
      return {...state, content: action.value};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

export default function LessonManager() {

    const [editing, toggleEditor] = React.useState(true);

    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    const value = React.useMemo(() => {
      return {
        state,
        dispatch,
        editing,
        toggleEditor,
      }
    }, [state, editing]);

    return (

      <ManagerContext.Provider value={value}>

        <div className='box-default expand'>

          <div className='handle' style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%', cursor: 'grab'}}>

              <LessonMenu />

          </div>

          <LessonContents />

        </div>

      </ManagerContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

I am not completely sure this is the best approach to solve this problem, but it works fine.